# Is there some mechanism to enforce nested interfaces are implemented in abstract classes in Python?

Tags: python, inner-classes, abc

I want to create a class that has some nested class that defines some contract in Python. A tenable example is a typed config object. My attempt at this is below:

```
from typing import Mapping
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    # If you want to implement BaseClass, you must also implement BaseConfig
    class BaseConfig(metaclass=ABCMeta):
        @abstractmethod
        def to_dict(self) -> Mapping:
            """Converts the config to a dictionary"""
```

But unfortunately I can instantiate a subclass of `BaseClass` without implementing `BaseConfig`:

```
class Foo(BaseClass):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
```

Is there some way to enforce that a subclass must implement an inner class, too?

Comment: This isn't supported by `abc`  as far as I know. Nested classes aren't a common pattern in Python. My advice would be to just pull the class out into the module level to begin with ...

Comment: That's sort of what I expected. Very disappointing.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use a nested class?

Comment: For the same reason you'd define methods operating on `abstractmethod`s in a base class: so you can operate at a higher level of abstraction. I can't do that if the, e.g., config is defined at the module level.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What, exactly, can you not do with another class defined at the module level? It seems just as abstract as a class that exists in another classes' namespace...

Comment: Something like this: https://repl.it/repls/FriendlyItchyGravity. The semantics behind `self.Inner(...)` are certainly not possible at the module level, but likely aren't possible at all in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like this is currently possible. The closest thing is to create two abstract classes (corresponding to outer and inner classes) and to force the implementer to provide the `cls` constructor for the concrete inner class; e.g.:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Inner(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __str__(self):
        pass

class Outer(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    inner_cls = Inner

    def shout(self, *args, **kwargs):
        inner = self.inner_cls(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"My inner is {inner}!!!")

class FooInner(Inner):
    def __str__(self):
        return "FooInner"

class FooOuter(Outer):
    inner_cls = FooInner
```

This requires `Inner` to have at least one `abstractmethod` otherwise it can be instantiated as a default `inner_cls` implementation.